# Tangent of a curve formula. Why is there a $\frac{1}{t}$?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

This is from my textbook:

[image]

I don't get why a vector in the direction of L is defined as:

$$\frac{1}{{\delta}T} [r(t + {\delta}T) - r(t)$$

Where does the division by delta t come from?

Here is an accompanying image:

[image]

Comment: Where do you see a $\frac{1}{t}$?

Comment: Slope is "rise over run". $\Delta t$ is the run. Make $\Delta t \to 0$ to get the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just another way of writing

$$\frac{r(t + \Delta t)-r(t)}{\Delta t}$$

which, as your textbook says, becomes the derivative $r'(t)$ when you take the limit as $\Delta t \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Ponder that without this "normalizing" denominator,

$$\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}(\mathbf r(t+\Delta t)-\mathbf r(t))=0.$$

What we need is

$$\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{\Delta\mathbf r}{\Delta t}.$$